# Error converting data type nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, .net

I have a problem and i dont know where the problem lies.My visual studio throws an exception when i enter the details and click on the submit button on my REGISTER page.I dont know if the problem lies in my SQL query or my code.So i am posting both

This is my Sql query:

```
        Create proc spRegisteredUsers

        @Name nvarchar(100),
        @UserName nvarchar(100),
        @Password nvarchar(200),
        @ContactNo int,
        @Email nvarchar(200)
         as
        Begin

       Declare @Count int
       Declare @ReturnCode int

       Select @Count = COUNT(UserName)
       from tblRegisteredUsers where UserName=@UserName
       if @Count>0
       Begin
       Set @ReturnCode= -1
       End
       Else
       Begin
       Set @ReturnCode= 1
       Insert into tblRegisteredUsers values(@Name,@UserName,@Password,@ContactNo,@Email)
       End
       Select @ReturnCode as ReturnValue
        End
```

whereas i get an exception on the line below:

```
           protected void btnRegSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
         if (Page.IsValid)
          {
          string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AK"].ConnectionString;
           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
           {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegisteredUsers", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter Name = new SqlParameter("@Name", txtRegName.Text);
            SqlParameter UserName = new SqlParameter("@UserName", txtRegUsername.Text);
            SqlParameter Password = new SqlParameter("@Password", txtRegPassword.Text);
            SqlParameter ContactNo = new SqlParameter("@ContactNo", txtRegContact.Text);
            SqlParameter Email = new SqlParameter("@Email", txtRegEmail.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(Name);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Password);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(ContactNo);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Email);

            con.Open();
            int ReturnCode = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (ReturnCode == -1)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "UserName already exists.";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

One funny thing i saw.When i remove Name and ContactNo fields from the table,stored procedure and cs code.IT WORKS.

Comment: Not much useful, post the complete error and how do you add parameters to your command?

Comment: Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

Comment: Please post the definition of `tblRegisteredUsers` and of `cmd`. Thanks

Comment: What flavor of `SQL` are you using?

Comment: the exception points the below line,so i think the below line is faulty            int ReturnCode =(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: i use sql server 2012 @MilenPavlov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead:

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
           {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegisteredUsers", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //use long instead...
            long Contact = Convert.ToInt64(txtRegContact.Text); //convert to long here 

            SqlParameter Name = new SqlParameter("@Name", txtRegName.Text);
            SqlParameter UserName = new SqlParameter("@UserName", txtRegUsername.Text);
            SqlParameter Password = new SqlParameter("@Password", txtRegPassword.Text);

            SqlParameter ContactNo = new SqlParameter("@ContactNo", Contact);

            SqlParameter Email = new SqlParameter("@Email", txtRegEmail.Text);
            ......
```

you're passing a string and SQL Procedure expects int for ContactNo.

Comment: Now i get an altogether different error "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32." so i changed the contactno from int to bigint in tables and stored procedures.However,i didnt change the code.

Comment: is there an error after `bigint` change? Maybe is better to have a `varchar` for contact info?

Comment: I was thinking of trying it this way.Worked like a charm.I think m sorted now.Thanks for ton bro.You are the man.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably getting error in first line. Try this:

```
int ReturnCode = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Comment: It didnt help.I am getting the same old error message when i try to submit details.

Comment: ExecuteScalar() is returning something that cannot be cast to an int, and thus you are see error. So the first thing you can check is what ExecuteScalar() is really return. You can use the debugger, or output "ExecuteScalar().GetType().ToString()", and that will give you the type of what is being returned.

Comment: ok will do that.in the meantime,i have posted the whole code.please check if its helpful.

Comment: it returns an object.

Comment: can you add Quickwatch and take screenshot to here? I need see the object's detail. [Info about Quickwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx)